# Not able to select value displayed in drop down 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:' displayed

Tags: selenium-webdriver

@Being at beginners, I am stuck on the below as I have tried the whole day but not able to select from the drop down.

Enter text,drop down is displayed select a value.

reference site I am using is www.irctc.co.in...JUST FOR TEST

Using eclispe java at my end

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='stationFrom']")).sendKeys("PUN");
Select test = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id
    ='no_0a_autocomplete_list']/li/span[text()='(PUNE)']")));
```

When I tried checking the select xpath in firebug, it displays the correct path, that is after PUN was entered.However when test is run it fails with the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=29.0.1547.76)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 29 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
```

I tried the solution at this question: 
[Need to select drop down value using xpath in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000199/need-to-select-drop-down-value-using-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver), but it did not work.

Comment: Can you please give html content of dropdown? It would help to answer your question.

Comment: Hi TDHM,
Station From...where I type PUN 
a)<input class="txtfld autocomplete_text" type="text" onfocus="defaultText4();" onblur="defaultText3();" onkeyup="xmlhttpPost(document.BookTicketForm.stationFrom);" value="" size="22" name="stationFrom"...> Drop down is displayed b) <ol id="no_0a_autocomplete_list" class="autocomplete_list"..."> <li class="item current_item" onselect="this.text.value ='PUNE JN (PUNE)'; "> Please refer to Xpath above that I had used
Thanks VS

Comment: Please add the additional content to your answer. It's much easier to read formatted code.

Comment: @Seanny
<input class="txtfld autocomplete_text" type="text" onfocus="defaultText4();" onblur="defaultText3();" onkeyup="xmlhttpPost(document.BookTicketForm.stationFrom);" value="" size="22" name="stationFrom"...> Drop down is displayed 
<ol id="no_0a_autocomplete_list" class="autocomplete_list"..."> <li class="item current_item" onselect="this.text.value ='PUNE JN (PUNE)'; ">
Code
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='stationFrom']")).sendKeys("PUN"); 
Select test = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id ='no_0a_autocomplete_list']/li/span[text()='(PUNE)']")));

Comment: What I meant was click the edit button on your answer, paste in the code and then format the code so that it is easier to read and so that future readers do not have to dig through the comments.

Comment: @Seanny123 the case I was trying worked.

Comment: If you've found a solution for your answer, please post it as an answer and update your question. Alternatively, if the solution is trivial enough to be not totally helpful for other users, delete your question.

Comment: @Seanny123 Thanks for pointing...Solution was below
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='stationFrom']")).sendKeys("DEL");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='no_0a_autocomplete_list']/li[8]")).click();

Comment: @VS - He means, scroll down to the answer box below, provide your answer there and click "Post Your Answer".  Similarly, if you need to add code to clarify your question, click the edit button just below your original question, and add it there.  Code posted in comments longer than one or two simple statements becomes very difficult to read or understand.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was below
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='stationFrom']")).sendKeys("DEL"); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='no_0a_autocomplete_list']/li[8]")).click()‌​;